# Array combinate　to savle Traversing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two JavaScript arrays:

var array1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]];

I want the output to be:
[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,3,7],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[1,4,7],[2,3,5],[2,3,6],[2,3,7],[2,4,5],[2,4,6],[2,4,7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I did find a better answer for this question . and I forgot to push it. now I will do it**

```
var arr = [
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6,7]
];
/* what I want is
    [[1],[2]]                                    arr i=0
    [[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]]                    arr i=1
    [[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,3,7],.....[2,4,7]]       arr i=2
*/
function comarr(arr){
   var narr = [[]];//empty
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     var barr = [];
     for(var m=0;m<narr.length;m++){
       for(var n=0;n<arr[i].length;n++){
         barr.push(narr[m].concat(arr[i][n]))
       }
     }
     narr = barr;
   }
   return narr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each element of each individual array. The solution below might only work for three nested-arrays but if you need a solution to work with a variable number of nested-arrays, you may need a recursive function.

```js
var array1 = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7]
];
var outputArrays = [];
array1[0].forEach(function(firstElement) {
  array1[1].forEach(function(secondElement) {
    array1[2].forEach(function(thirdElement) {
      outputArrays.push([firstElement, secondElement, thirdElement]);
    });
  });
});
console.log('output arrays: ',outputArrays);
```

Comment: this can do the arry1 but can not solve arry1 length is changed. 

for example array1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9],[0,11]]
we can not how long the array1 and we foreach how many times.